# Undefined method "each" in Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby

The new Mac OS update moved the system Ruby up to 2.0, which is great, but now I'm seeing errors in a lot of my scripts that I don't know how to fix. Specifically, I had code that called for files using mdfind and then read them, like this:

```
files = %x{mdfind -onlyin /Users/Username/Dropbox/Tasks 'kMDItemContentModificationDate >= "$time.today(-1)"'}
files.each do |file|
```

Now I'm getting an error that says

```
undefined method `each' for #<String:0x007f83521865c8> (NoMethodError)"
```

It seems as if each now needs a qualifier. I tried each_line but that yielded additional errors down the line. Is there a simple replacement for this that I'm overlooking?

Comment: String doesn't have method `each`. It won't work in any modern ruby.

Comment: do `puts files.class`,you will get the answer..why the error.

Comment: Sergio - this exact script worked on 1.8.7, just yesterday.

Comment: Apparently, there **was** String#each in 1.8. But not anymore.

Comment: Arup - I'm not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: @craigeley: yeah, I checked, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Sergio - any idea for a fix/replacement?

Comment: @craigeley I mean check the class of the object being referenced by files..then you get to know why the `#each no meth error` comes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby 1.8 used to have [`String#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-each) which was doing implicit splitting.

> #### each(separator=$/) {|substr| block } => str
>
> Splits str using the supplied parameter as the record separator ($/ by default), passing each substring in turn to the supplied block. If a zero-length record separator is supplied, the string is split into paragraphs delimited by multiple successive newlines.

Explicit splitting should work in modern rubies, I believe.

```
files.split($/).each do |file|
```

Where `$/` is newline char. You can use explicit char, since your script is not portable anyway.

```
files.split("\n").each do |file|
```

### Update

or you can just use an alias of now-extinct `each`

```
files.each_line do |file|
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks, Sergio.

Comment: [`String.each_line`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-each_line) wants to be your friend.